# Inter Process Communication between 2 running processes

Tags: windows, air, process, ipc

I have one Windows application and an AIR (Adobe) application. Both the applications are running in background. Whenever the user wants they can bring it up to desktop and display the UI.

Now, When the user performs some action using Windows client, i need to trigger some event in another client i.e. AIR Client. Is there any way to implement this scenario. Will classical IPC techniques works with Flex Based AIR application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have successfully implemented using localhost sockets.